# How to force sql-maven-plugin to ignore failling sqls

Tags: java, sql, maven, sql-maven-plugin

I have a build which copies schema from test environment (creates sqls) and executes (using sql-maven-plugin) those sql on local-database. The problem is some views, stored procedures are broken on test environment. I need to ignore broken sqls (with wrong views etc) and carry on the build. I need to do this dynamically meaning eg we have sqls A,B,C and A sql is broken, I don't want to fail whole build but add some waring and executes next sqls B, C.. till the end.

Is this possible? Any ideas? Workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found it...

[link to documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html)

onError:

```
Action to perform if an error is found. Possible values are abort and continue.
Type: java.lang.String
Since: 1.0
Required: No
Expression: ${onError}
Default: abort
```

I added to config:

```
<configuration>
   (...)
   <onError>continue</onError>
</configuration>
```